# Running tests on travis using mysql

Tags: java, mysql, maven, junit, travis-ci

I've been trying for the last week or so to make integration tests work on travis for a school project. I've debugged a fair bit of the project but now I'm blocked and need external help.

To give a bit of context, so far, I've debugged the java project so that the tests can be launched from eclipse or from maven in command line. I've worked on the travis file so that a database is created, the database scripts run and the java tests launch. However, the tests fail on travis because of a "table missing" in the database.

[This is a link to our repo.](https://github.com/SOEN341-Group1/KoalaCal/tree/BE-JUnit-Testing)

This is the travis.yml file's code:

```
language : java
jdk: 
- oraclejdk8
service:
  - mysql
before_script:
  - mysql -e 'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS koalatest'
  - mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS koalatest;'  
  - mysql -u root --default-character-set=utf8 koalatest < backend/koalacal-backend/koalacal.sql
script: cd backend && cd koalacal-backend && mvn test -X
after_success:
  - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

The java project that is being built and run by maven is located under rootfolder -> backend -> koalacal-backend.

[Here is a link to the error log maven produces on travis.](https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/217945891/log.txt)

This line seems to be the source of the error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'koalatest.Calendar' doesn't exist

I have two hypothesis:

1- The sql script that creates all the tables is not being run properly by travis.

To test this hypothesis, I changed the name of the script called by travis. As expected, I got an error saying that travis can't find the file. So at least, I know that this line of code causes travis to look up at an sql file.

```
- mysql -u root --default-character-set=utf8 koalatest < backend/koalacal-backend/koalacal.sql
```

That being said, I have no idea if the file is run properly on the database.

For the sake of putting all relevant informations in this post, [here is a link to the database script.](https://github.com/SOEN341-Group1/KoalaCal/blob/BE-JUnit-Testing/backend/koalacal-backend/koalacal.sql)

2- The tests can't connect properly to the database.

Here is the config file that contain the info regarding which database to connect to:

    `TestInstance=true
    user=root
    password=
    serverName=localhost
    databaseName=koalacal
    portNumber=3306`

```
testUser=root
testPassword=
testServerName=127.0.0.1
testDatabaseName=koalatest
testPortNumber=3306</code>
```

If the parameter TestInstance is set to true, the tests take the informations testUser, testPassword, testServerName, testDatabaseName and testPortNumber to connect to the relevant database.

I believe the connection informations currently contained in the config file match how the travis documentation says we need to connect to a mysql database. I tried to change the testUser to something invalid (like root3) and got error messages as expected.

Maybe somehow the tests can't connect to the database and don't produce a related error message, but I doubt it.

Can someone look at my problem and see if I've missed something obvious (or not)? I don't know what else to try and I don't want to be blocked one more week on a technical issue.

Comment: Try to move your database creating script to `before_install:
  - mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE myapp_test;'`

Comment: Take a look here: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#Note-on-test-database

Comment: Nice try but I get the same result:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'koalatest.Calendar' doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who may google travis mysql and has a similar error to the one I had, I solved my problem.

The error was caused by a case sensitivity issue. The java code tried to connect to tables like 'Calendar' and 'Event' while the sql script created the tables 'calendar' and 'event'.

It took a long time to troubleshoot this because the case sensitivity didn't pose any problem on my machine. Maven can run its tests properly without any issue. It's only on the travis servers that case sensitivity of the tables started to matter.